# How to avoid Foreign Keys constraints for all tables in DB truncate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

for designing purposes i need to truncate all DB which has lots of FK's. I cannot use DELETE command simply because some tables set with Identity of TinyInts and contain about 150 items.

this is a query ( truncate all tables in selected DB ) i'm trying to run

```
Declare @t varchar (1024)
Declare tbl_cur cursor for  
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN tbl_cur

FETCH NEXT  from tbl_cur INTO @t

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE '+ @t)
FETCH NEXT  from tbl_cur INTO @t
END

CLOSE tbl_cur
DEALLOCATE tbl_Cur
```

What the best and easiest way to achieve truncate on DB with many FK's ?

Comment: What do you want to happen to records that reference the to-be-deleted rows? Or are you trying to delete all rows in all related tables?

Comment: @lc, I want to completely clean DB from all the data, just keep the structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the reason you are avoiding delete is simply in order to avoid the issue with identity columns you can just delete then use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

to reset them to zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to delete all rows in all related tables, can you drop the constraints, truncate the tables, then create the constraints again?

Or...[this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=65341) could be useful as well. Looks like it loops through from the bottom of the dependency tree up until everything's gone.

Comment: This is hell of the job to do, there must be easier way...
Easier way would be generate scripts for tables, sps and views and just re-create database again... Less scripting will be required..

Comment: @lc, seems that link in your posts doesn't do the job simply because it loops through tables and if table has constraints it uses delete instead of truncate...

anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all foreign keys, truncate tables, then enable the foreign keys back.

Disable: ALTER TABLE table_name NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Enable: ALTER TABLE table_name CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL